# How to make a variable from an array

Tags: php, mysql, arrays

I am trying to assign array items into an array.
Here is my code;

```
$sqlText['attach']="SELECT attachments.disk_directory, 
                attachments.disk_filename, 
                attachments.digest,
                attachments.filename
                FROM attachments
                WHERE container_id = $myPage
                GROUP BY digest";

$sqlQuery_MainMenu = mysql_db_query($db, $sqlText['attach'], $connection) or die("DB CON ERROR");
$directories=array();
$files=array();
$file_names=array();
while($mm_Content=mysql_fetch_array($sqlQuery_MainMenu)){
    $directories[]=$mm_Content[disk_directory];
    $files[]=$mm_Content[disk_filename];
    $file_names[]=$mm_Content[filename];

}   
foreach($directories as $index => $directory){
 $attachment = $directory.'/'.$files[$index].'<pre>';

  }
    foreach($file_names as $file_name){
 $file_name.'<pre>';

  }
```

My aim is that get all results from foreach and assign them into a variable and use that variable later.

What i do only brings one item from array. I tried php extract and couple of other things but none worked. 
I simply want to assign foreach loop to a variable
Your suggestions are appreciated very much.

```
foreach($directories as $index => $directory){
 echo $directory.'/'.$files[$index].'<pre>';

  }
```

Returns with 5 results for instance;

```
/documents/directory/filename.jpg
/documents/directory/filename1.jpg
/documents/directory5/somename.jpg
```

I just want get this results from foreach loop and assign them into a variable. When i use this new variable i want it to have values that is above example.

I want to send this attachments to PHPMailer attachments
Let's say have two variables files and names that has results from foreach loop. 
On PHPMailer;

```
$mail->addAttachment($files, $names);
```

If this does not work i am going to change my code to;

```
foreach($directories as $index => $directory){
 $attachment = .'/'.$files[$index].'<pre>';
    '$mail->addAttachment('.$attachment')';

  }
```

And forget about file_names.

Comment: What are you trying to do and what is the problem you are encountering? If you can be a bit clearer, it would help.

Comment: @ NaijaProgrammer Thank you for reminding i updated my question.My aim is that get all results from foreach and assign them into a variable and use that variable later.

Answer (score 0):

You can debug variables content with var_dump or return:

```
var_dump($var); // Automatic echo
print_r($var); // Automatic echo
print_r($var, true); // Return
```

You can iterate through a variable with foreach.

Comment: And where is the answer besides all these comments and hints ?

Comment: Thank you so much for the answer but this is not what i look for. I want to get all results from the foreach and use it on a variable. Although `var_dump($var);` also prints only one result on my case.

Answer (score 0):

I may not fully understand what you are trying to do, but I observed one or two things in your code. First, in the `while` loop, you `$mm_Content` array members should have quotes around them. Currently, what you have is:

```
while($mm_Content=mysql_fetch_array($sqlQuery_MainMenu))
{
   $directories[]=$mm_Content[disk_directory];
   $files[]=$mm_Content[disk_filename];
   $file_names[]=$mm_Content[filename];
}
```

You can re-write it this way:

```
while($mm_Content=mysql_fetch_array($sqlQuery_MainMenu))
{
   $directories[]=$mm_Content["disk_directory"];
   $files[]=$mm_Content["disk_filename"];
   $file_names[]=$mm_Content["filename"];
}
```

That being said, your foreach loop is not echoing what you want because on each subsequent iteration, you overwrite the previous value in the `$attachment` variable with the new one. To make it hold every value from the loop, you'd have to go with how you did it for the `$directories` variable: declare it as an array and assign each subsequent loop value to a new array element. Applying this principle, your code should look like below:

```
$attachments = array(); //create and initialise the attachments array
$counter = 0; //create and initialise a counter variable
foreach($directories as $index => $directory)
{
   $attachment[$counter] = $directory.'/'.$files[$index];
}
foreach($file_names as $file_name)
{
    $attachment[$counter] .= '<pre>'. $file_name.'</pre>';

    ++$counter; //increment the counter variable
}
```

Then, to print out the values, you'd do:

```
foreach($attachments AS $attachment)
{
   echo $attachment;
}
```

Or, using a `for` loop:

```
for($i = 0; $i < count($attachments) $i++)
{
   echo $attachments[$i];
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your help and answer. My aim is simply assigning foreach loop to a variable.
I have tried your suggestion but it brought Array as a result.